# IBM Watson Visual Recognition Text Prebuilt model

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I have a problem with the Visual Recognition Service. I found the text model in the description in [documentation](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/visual-recognition-overview.html%20.). But in my Lite plan, I have only General, Food and Explicit Prebuild models.

See the image below:

[image]

How can I get access to the Text Prebuild model in Visual Recognition Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, I found the answer. [One](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-release-notes#12september2019) of the last releases says, that this feature is closed and there are no plans for another beta or general release.